# Is it possible to have an optional with/as statement in python?

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

Instead of this:

```
file = open(f)
do_something(file)
file.close()
```

it's better to use this:

```
with open(f) as file:
    do_something(file)
```

What if I have something like this?

```
if f is not None:
    file = open(f)
else:
    file = None
do_something(file)
if file is not None:
    file.close()
```

Where `do_something` also has an `if file is None` clause, and still does something useful in that case - I **don't** want to just skip `do_something` if `file` is `None`.

Is there a sensible way of converting this to with/as form? Or am I just trying to solve the optional file problem in a wrong way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For Python *3.7* or higher, then you can use the [`nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) for stand-in purposes:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

none_context = contextmanager(lambda: iter([None]))()
# <contextlib.GeneratorContextManager at 0x1021a0110>

with (open(f) if f is not None else none_context) as FILE:
    do_something(FILE)
```

---

For older Python versions, you can build one yourself on-the-fly with an optional `None`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

none_context = contextmanager(lambda: iter([None]))()
# <contextlib.GeneratorContextManager at 0x1021a0110>

with (open(f) if f is not None else none_context) as FILE:
    do_something(FILE)
```

It creates a context that returns `None`. The `with` will either produce `FILE` as a file object, or `None`. But the `None` type will have a proper `__exit__`

---

Another solution would be to just write it like this:

```
if f is not None:
    with open(f) as FILE:
        do_something(FILE)
else:
    do_something(f)
```

(`file` is a builtin btw )

Comment: @sberry -  I saw that we almost had the same thing, really close to eachother :-)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid repeating `do_something`, since it's a bigger chunk of code in the real case (though I can stick it in a function, etc). But maybe this is the best I can do.

Comment: I just added a fun little example of how to do what you want.

Comment: Note that `none_context` can only be used once.  I prefer to make it a callable: `def none_context(a=None): return contextmanager(iter)([a])`

Comment: Also, it fails if an exception is raised (`AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute 'throw'`).  This is more robust: `def none_context(a=None): return contextmanager(lambda: (x for x in [a]))()`

Comment: None of these solutions, including those in these comments, seem to work for me in all situations with python 2.7.12 - they either raise `AttributeError: __exit__` immediately, or `AttributeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute 'throw'` when an exception occurs and `none_context` is the selected context.

Comment: contextlib.ExitStack() is a better solution...

Answer (score 18):

Since Python 3.7, you can also do

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext

with (open(f) if f else nullcontext()) as file:
    # Do something with `file`
    pass
```

See the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to solve all of your concerns.

```
if file_name is not None:
    with open(file_name) as fh:
        do_something(fh)
else:
    do_something(None)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid repeating `do_something`, since it's a bigger chunk of code in the real case (though I can stick it in a function, etc). But maybe this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.3 and above, you can use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to handle this scenario nicely

```
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    file = stack.enter_context(open(f)) if f else None
    do_something(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
if file:  # it checks for None, false values no need for "if file is None"
    with open(file) as FILE:
        do_something(FILE)
else:
    FILE=None
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself very clear. Hopefully the edited version of the question makes more sense. I actually want do_something to run even if FILE is None - it has other useful functionality, the file-related section of it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7 supports [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext), which can be used to avoid creating your own dummy context manager.

This examples shows how you can conditionally open a file or use the `stdout`:

```
import contextlib
import sys

def write_to_file_or_stdout(filepath=None, data):
    with (
            open(filepath, 'w') if filepath is not None else
            contextlib.nullcontext(sys.stdout)
    ) as file_handle:
        file_handle.write(data)
```

`contextlib.nullcontext()` can be called without any arguments if the value can be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

For the people like me who came here for the title: **Is it possible to have an optional with/as statement in python?** wanting to use an optional `with` clause returning another object.

visit [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to learn more, but it looks something like this:

```py
obj = 'anything'
with (return_normal_object(obj) if True else open(path)) as file:
   # use file
   assert file == 'anything'
```

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def return_normal_object(obj):
    yield obj
```

Answer (score -6):

While all of the other answers are excellent, and preferable, note that the `with` expression may be *any* expression, so you can do:

```
with (open(file) if file is not None else None) as FILE:
    pass
```

Note that if the `else` clause were evaluated, to yield `None` this would result in an exception, because `NoneType` does not support the appropriate operations to be used as a context manager.

Comment: Wait...are you sure this works? None type would crash because it does not have an `AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: @jdi - damn, you're right, it does crash... Back to the drawing board. :(

Comment: @jdi: Fair point. I want to emphasise the syntax and possibilities here, though. I'll edit to make clear that this would fail on execution.

Comment: @Marcin: I ended up coming up with an on-the-fly NoneType context, that works the way you were intending with this, in my answer.

Comment: Not even `__exit__`, on Python 3.6 this fails with `AttributeError: __enter__`.

Comment: @jimbo1qaz Read the whole answer, please.

Comment: @Marcin I fail to the see the value this answer brings. Can you elaborate?