# How to have multiple dummy file writers in a with statement?

Tags: python, iterator, with-statement

I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168252/1983854) of [Is it possible to have an optional with/as statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12168208/1983854) that you can have a dummy file writer with [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html). I want, however, to open multiple dummy file writers in a with statement context.

Say I create two dummy files: `touch a` and `touch b`.

Given the first part of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from contextlib import contextmanager

# File names
fa="a"
fb="b"

# Dummy file handler
none_context = contextmanager(lambda: iter([None]))()
```

This addition works with a single dummy file writer (it prints `2`):

```
printing=False
with (open(fa) if printing else none_context) as writter:
    print 1 if printing else 2
```

This also works, because we are indeed reading files (it prints `1`):

```
printing=True
with (open(fa, "r") if printing else none_context) as writter, \
    (open(fb, "r") if printing else none_context) as another_writter:
    print 1 if printing else 2
```

However, it doesn't work if we are using two dummy file writers:

```
printing=False
with (open(fa, "r") if printing else none_context) as writter, \
    (open(fb, "r") if printing else none_context) as another_writter:
    print 1 if printing else 2
```

It shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy_opener.py", line 23, in <module>
    with (open(fa, "r") if printing else none_context) as writter, \
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 19, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield")
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

Why is this happening? And also: how can I make this multiple `with open` commands work with a dummy file writer?

Comment: Have you tried the *"more robust"* version from the comment (`def none_context(a=None): return contextmanager(lambda: (x for x in [a]))()`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it works, thanks! Still wondering why my approach wasn't working, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails as you have already consumed the iterator on the first call, if you call `none_context()` in the with block the original code would work:

```
none_context = contextmanager(lambda: iter([None]))
printing=False

with open(fa, "r") if printing else none_context() as writter, \
    open(fb, "r") if printing else none_context() as another_writter:
    print 1 if printing else 2
```

You can see using your original code that if you add a `None` for each open then the code will work as expected:

```
none_context = contextmanager(lambda: iter([None,None,None]))()
printing=False

with open(fa, "r") if printing else none_context as writter, \
    open(fb, "r") if printing else none_context as another_writter,\
    open(fb, "r") if printing else none_context as another_writer3:
    print 1 if printing else 2
```